# PL/SQL with Java to delete tables older than 3 days

Tags: plsql

For this follwing PL/SQL statement 
Query to drop tables 10 days older

```
String s = "begin
    for xx in ( select tableName from ALLTABLES where regexp_like(tableName, '  ABCD[[:digit:]]{8}'  ) and to_date(substr(tableName, -8), ' yyyymmdd' ) <  trunc(sysdate) - 3) 
    loop
    execute immediate ' drop table'  ||xx.tableName ||'  purge'  ;
    end loop;
    end;"
```

I am using Callable Statement

```
CallableStatement cs = null;
cs = conn.prepareCall(s);
cs.execute(rplSql);
```

But this seems to show invalid SQL Statement , Any idea ??

Comment: The java tag doesn't look relevant, apart if you tested it using the psql console and it worked.

Comment: Yes I added escape sequences to it. Coz I am parsing this from xml.

Comment: And it works when you execute it outside of Java ?

Comment: There is no `ALLTABLES` in Oracle. And having a date in the table name sounds like a *real* messed up design.

Comment: It's a bit dangerous to use an account with DROP TABLES permission to execute arbitrary SQL that's parsed out of an XML file.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name : Those are dummy variables .

Comment: @user2978621 Don't put a space between @ and the user name, this defeats the purpose which is automatically notifying the user.

Comment: Try the following: `SELECT o.OBJECT_NAME AS TABLENAME, o.CREATED FROM ALL_OBJECTS o WHERE o.OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE' AND REGEXP_LIKE(o.OBJECT_NAME, '  ABCD[[:digit:]]{8}') AND o.CREATED < TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '3' DAY`. Not tested on animals - you'll be first! Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select table_Name from ALL_TABLES where regexp_like(table_Name, '  ABCD[[:digit:]]{8}')
```

in for statement